# How to get data from Gson link

Tags: java, json, gson

this is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import com.google.gson.*;

public class GsonDecode {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException{

        String sURL = "http://pubapi.cryptsy.com/api.php?method=orderdata"; //just a string

        // Connect to the URL using java's native library
        URL url = new URL(sURL);
        HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        request.connect();

        // Convert to a JSON object to print data
        JsonParser jp = new JsonParser(); //from gson
        JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent())); //convert the input stream to a json element
        JsonElement jsonElement = root.getAsJsonObject().get("return");

    }
}
```

I need to get only the "label" of each market from this JSON link. All other info is unnecessarily

Whats the easiest way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't unless the API is designed for that. Ask API developers for that if it's implementer they'll provide documentation or other URL for that.

Or you can download whole json and get all names like this

```
JsonElement jsonElement = root.getAsJsonObject().get("return");
Set<Map.Entry<String,JsonElement>> entries = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().entrySet();
for(Map.Entry<String,JsonElement> entry:entries) {
   System.out.println(entry.getKey());  //get keys
}
```

Comment: Method: getmarkets , 

Inputs: n/a ,

Outputs: Array of Active Markets , 

marketid    - Integer value representing a market , 
label     -   Name for this market.
Here is the API

Comment: try iteration over all entries and getting keys